# php doesnt compare variables but does hard coded value

Tags: php

I have a script that works and loops showing various results, but i want to chek if result match a given variable. It works it i enter it like '4' but wont if entered as a $myArray?

The code is

```
$vehicle_req = "4";

echo "Vehicle required is : ".$v[$vehicle_req]."<BR><BR>";
//----- GET COMPANIES IN AREA --------
echo "Companies in the area :<BR><BR>";

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(53.83428999999999) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-3.0399797000000035) ) + sin( radians(53.83428999999999) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM clients HAVING distance < 30 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $name = $row['name'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $vehicles = $row['vehicles'];
    echo "<B>".$id." -</B> ".$name."<BR>".$vehicles."<BR>";

    $myArray = explode(':', $vehicles);
    foreach($myArray as $my_Array){
        echo "<BR>".$v[$my_Array]."<BR>";
        echo $my_Array."<BR>";
        if($my_Array == '4')
            echo "MATCH vehicle 4<BR>";
    }
}
```

Comment: `$my_array` is just one element (string) in the `$myArray` array so they would never be equal. (I'm assuming your referring to the if statement in your foreach loop?) What are you trying to do?

Comment: EDIT: shouldnt this `  echo "<BR>".$v[$my_Array]."<BR>";`  Be this 
`  echo "<BR>".$my_Array."<BR>";`    it's a string...
Do a `print_r($myArray); before your foreach, see if it actually has what you are trying to match, and if it is actually a numeric array value, `if($my_Array == 4) ` ie; un-encapsulated, should work

Comment: Sorted it :

$myArray = explode(':', $vehicles);
foreach($myArray as $my_Array){
//echo "<BR>".$v[$my_Array]."<BR>";
//echo $my_Array."<BR>";
$new1 = $my_Array;
if($vehicle_req === $new1)
echo "<BR>".$name." has a ".$v[$vehicle_req]." in the area required! <BR>";
}